# Proper usage of FileTree

Tags: groovy, gradle

I'm having trouble getting the correct signature of filetree.  I receive a closure in a method and I'm wanting to pass that along to the correct fileTree method.

```
def licenseFiles(Closure closure) {
   licenseFiles2 = project.fileTree( closure )
```

I call the method like so:

```
licenseFiles { dir: 'src' }
```

It seems to call the [fileTree( Object )](http://bit.ly/xFrMJE) method.  Any ideas what is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`project.fileTree { dir: 'src' }` is incorrect syntax (for any version of Gradle). Correct syntax (checked for 1.0-m8) is `project.fileTree('src')`, `project.fileTree(dir: 'src')`, or `project.fileTree { from 'src' }`.